# Why can't i open text editor when working with postgresql on terminal?

Tags: postgresql

I know command "\e" when working with POSTGRESQL will open text editor so I can insert text and execute queries from there. But when I use "\e", the terminal just simply inserts a new line with character "1". I can't also exit from this text by using Ctrl+C.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This behavior seems to correspond to [ed](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ed_(text_editor)) as the editor.

You need to set an environment variable to the editor of your choice. From the psql [manual](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/app-psql.html):

> PSQL_EDITOR
>     EDITOR
>     VISUAL
>        Editor used by the \e, \ef, and \ev commands. These variables are examined in the
>        order listed; the first that is set is used. If none of them is set, the default is
>              to use vi on Unix systems or notepad.exe on Windows systems.

According to the last sentence, you probably have `EDITOR` set to `ed`.
Aside from setting it in the caller environment, it can be changed from within psql with `\setenv EDITOR vi` for instance.

Comment: That's exactly the point. Thanks, Daniel.